# Calculate the integral for a general distribution function

Tags: probability-theory

$F$ is a distribution function .Take any $a \in \mathbb{R}$.  Then evaluate :
$\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}} (F(x+a)-F(x)) dx$

As it is a general distribution function , I cannot employ densities to solve this problem . Any insights or a complete solution will be very appreciated .

Comment: So you mean F is a cumulative distribution

Comment: @Tojrah Yes  , definitely !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int (F(x+a)-F(x))dx=\int \int I_{\{x< X\leq x+a\}}dPdx$ where $X$ is a random variable with distribution $F$. By Fubini's Theorem this can be written as $\int \int I_{\{X-a \leq x< X\}}dxdP=\int a dP=a$.

Comment: +1 Sir  @Kavi Rama Murty , what is the meaning of the notation $dP$ ? Can you please explain it more .

Comment: Any distribution function $F$ satisfies the equation  $F(x)=P\{x  \leq x\}$ for some random a variable $X$ defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F,P)$. I am using the measure $P$ on this probability space.

Comment: Sir , does the distribution function come equipped with the random variable $X$  and the probability measure $P$ ? Sir , is it possible to do this only using Riemann integration by putting $P[x<X \leq x+a ]$ in place of $F(x+a) - F(x)$ ?

Comment: It is very easy to construct $X$: you can simply take $\Omega =\mathbb R$, $\mathcal F=$ Borel sigma algebra and $P$ to be the unique measure which satisfied the equation$F(x)=P(-\infty,x])=F(x)$ for all $x$. Then take $X$ to be the  identity function on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

Answer that leaves out a random variable.

If $a\geq0$ then $F\left(x+a\right)-F\left(x\right)$ can be recognized
as integral $\int\mathbf{1}_{\left(x,x+a\right]}\left(y\right)dF\left(y\right)$.

Applying Fubini we find: $$\int F\left(x+a\right)-F\left(x\right)dx=\int\int\mathbf{1}_{\left(x,x+a\right]}\left(y\right)dF\left(y\right)dx=$$$$\int\int\mathbf{1}_{\left(x,x+a\right]}\left(y\right)dxdF\left(y\right)=\int\int\mathbf{1}_{\left[y-a,y\right)}\left(x\right)dxdF\left(y\right)=\int adF\left(y\right)=a$$

If $a<0$ then: $$\int F\left(x+a\right)-F\left(x\right)dx=-\int F\left(x\right)-F\left(x-\left(-a\right)\right)dx=-\int F\left(x+\left(-a\right)\right)-F\left(x\right)dx=-(-a)=a$$where the second equality is based on the fact that the Lebesgue measure is translation invariant.